# Sonar Runner not starting

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to configure Sonar 3.2 in my Windows 7 64 bit operating system with java 1.7.0_05.

When I start Sonar runner - 1.4, I am getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/batch/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:164)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.createClassLoader(Runner.java:176)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:84)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:67)
Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/batch/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:113)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:159)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:239)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:680)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3035)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3029)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapperIOUtils.copyLarge(BootstrapperIOUtils.java:63)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:109)
```

any solution to solve this issue is appreciated.

I am able to download hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar from `http://localhost:9000/batch/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar` in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your configuration details that you are running Sonar using a Java 7 VM: could you please try with Java 6?

That might not be the root cause, but I know we have users who reported some issues with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I get when I execute the runner without administrative privileges.

If you're launching the runner from a DOS prompt, try right-clicking on "Windows Command Processor" and choosing "Run as Administrator."